# UIDatePicker giving different time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uidatepicker

I have drag and drop `UIDatePicker` from `InterfaceBuilder` and in .h file i have done the outlet and actions as follows.

```
- (IBAction)DatePicker:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateSelected;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePickerOutlet;
```

and in appDelegate.m file i have assigned the following parameters to the `datePickerOutlet`

```
datePickerOutlet.calendar=[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
datePickerOutlet.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

but it is giving time as follows through `NSLog`

```
2012-09-03 15:42:45.365 DataTest[4213:207] 2012-09-03 10:10:28 +0000
2012-09-03 15:42:45.366 DataTest[4213:207] Asia/Kolkata
```

it should give output as

```
2012-09-03 15:42:45.365 DataTest[4213:207] 2012-09-03 3:42:45 +0000
2012-09-03 15:42:45.366 DataTest[4213:207] Asia/Kolkata
```

(which is the current time)

How to get the current time??in the picker it is showing correctly but when i select a date NSLog is giving other value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time shown is in GMT, u need to use localTimeZone or manually add +0530 hrs

```
datePickerOutlet.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

use this to set the local Time Zone. hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: i added datePickerOutlet.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; but it does not help.. I know adding 0530 hrs will surely help but being curious what is going wrong with the datePicker

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `-[NSDateFormatter stringFromDate:]` to format `NSDate`?